# Running Ruby unit tests with Rake

Tags: ruby, rake

I was investigating using the Rake build tool to automate running unit tests. I searched the web, but all the examples were for using rails. I usually just write small command-line programs or simple Sinatra applications.

So I came up with the following (probably bad) solution that just emulates what I would do on the command-line: (I just ran one unit test as an example.)

```
desc 'Run unit tests'
task :test do
    sh 'ruby -I lib test/test_entry.rb'
end
task :default => :test
```

It works, but I can't help thinking there must be a better way, just writing `require 'test/test_entry.rb'` doesn't work. I get `require` problems, Ruby can't find the `lib` directory, where all the files are.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use Rake::TestTask http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html . Put this into your Rake file and then run `rake test`:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['test/test*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

Comment: If you like organizing your tests into subdirectories, try `'test/**/test*.rb'` to accommodate that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `lib` directory is not included into ruby's loading path. You can fix it like that:

```
$:.unshift 'lib'
require 'test_entry'
```

or more reliable alternative that adds expanded path of `lib` directory to the loading path:

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib'))
require 'test_entry'
```

Btw, global variable `$:` has more verbose alias `$LOAD_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run tests written in Minitest:

1. Create `Rakefile` (or `rakefile`, `rakefile.rb`, `Rakefile.rb`) file in your app's root with the following contents:

```ruby
require 'minitest/test_task'

Minitest::TestTask.create
```

It is assumed that your test files have `_test` suffix and located under `test` directory.

2. Run `rake test`.

[Minitest rake files](https://github.com/minitest/minitest#rake-tasks-)