# Easier way to test gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am in the middle of writing a Ruby Gem, but was wondering if there is an easier way to "test" your gem without having to build it, install it and require it to test it out in an IRB console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git clone it in an arbitrary folder, add its lib path to `$:` in the rakefile if needed (you actually don't in this case, as RakeTest should add it for you), and run `rake test` directly.

From irb, proceed similarly: add the lib path to `$:` to bypass the packaged gem. But note that you'll need to reload it when you change it, so it's less convenient than rake.

For completeness, in case you or a future visitor is unfamiliar with Rake:

[Running Ruby unit tests with Rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017158/running-ruby-unit-tests-with-rake)

Comment: Ah gotcha! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I've added a ref to rake testing, just in case.