# run Ruby Unit Tests with Buildr

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, buildr

I am using buildr for some time now, but today I came over a little problem in connection to unit testing of ruby code.

So in my buildfile I have these lines:

```
define "ruby-project" do

    project.version = VERSION_NUMBER
    project.group = GROUP

    Rake::TestTask.new(:test_rb) do |t|
        t.warning = true
        t.verbose = true
        t.test_files = FileList['test/*.rb']
    end
    task test => [:test_rb]

end
```

running `buildr test` actually runs the tests, what is nice. The test is actually just that:

```
require 'test/unit'

class TestFileParse < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_fail
        assert(false, 'test to fail')
     end
end
```

As expected it fails, **BUT** what is strange for me is that buildr quits the build with that message:

```
sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Buildr aborted!
RuntimeError : Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -w -I"lib" -I"/var/lib/...]
```

Running `ruby file-with-failing-test-from-above.rp` does not throw a runtime error, instead it prints the test report on screen, what is what is what I want.

**Question**

How can I make Buildr run the unit tests without quitting with an `RuntimeError` if a test fails?

Greetings Philipp

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not too familiar with Ruby development, what involves Rake, I was looking for the wrong question. Instead of looking for: »how to run unit test with buildr«, the question should have been »how to run unit tests with rake«, because buildr is a kind of extended Rake (similar to the »maven-ant-relationship«). So everything one can do in Rake, one can do in buildr, too. Therefore on good SO answer to run [ruby unit tests](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Unit_testing) in buildr is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017158/running-ruby-unit-tests-with-rake).

Additionally it is possible to run [RSpec's](http://rspec.info/) with buildr, therefore one has two options:

1. set `project.test.using :rspec`, what involves the use of JRuby, so one has to set `JRUBY_HOME` (in my case `~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.9/`), or run buildr within jruby. In my case this slowed test execution down, because each time a jvm needed to be started.
2. Or one can use [rspec's rake task](http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/RakeTask#rspec_opts-instance_method) in [this manner](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/command-line/rake-task#default-options-with-passing-spec-%28prints-command-and-exit-status-is-0%29). I choose this method since my tests run much faster without the jvm overhead.

n.b. as the answer implies, I switched over to rspec.

Happy Testing/Speccing!